# Create a data source based on the spring profile

Tags: java, spring

I have two profiles in Spring: `first` and `second`. If I use the `first` profile, I want to create a datasource based on postgres, but if I use `second` I don't want any datasource created at all. I've defined my `JpaEntityConfig` class as:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties()
public class JpaEntityConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    ...
}
```

if I set `spring.profiles.active=first` then it works fine, however if I set it to `spring.profiles.active=second` then I'm getting the following error:

```
Field dataSource in com.package.JpaEntityConfig required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.
```

how can I get around this?

Comment: Without any data source how you  can configure the  jpa because it need a datsource bean to inject?

Comment: Seconding @YJR. Your `JpaEntityConfig` should also be created only if the respective profile is active.

Answer (score 1):

As JpaEntityConfig is expecting a DataSource you can make this optional if you so wish

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties()
public class JpaEntityConfig {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    DataSource dataSource;
```

Comment: This only sets the reference as null. If the code uses the variable, it’ll throw a NPE.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties()
@Profile("!second")
public class JpaEntityConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    ...
}
```

You can skip this jpa configuration when profile `second` is active as above.

Comment: I did that ... it gave the same error still ...

Comment: @Profile({"first"}) instead above